# Why is a class an instance of a string?

Tags: php

Suddenly faced this in PHP:

```
<?php
  class MyClass{}; 
  $a=new MyClass(); 
  $b="MyClass"; 
  var_dump($a instanceof $b);
```

Result:

```
bool(true)
```

Why is this true?

Comment: Because the `$a` object is an instance of the class named `MyClass`?

Comment: try it with `===` and its false, guess why

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: The same result can be seen in [PHP's own examples](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php#example-128)

Comment: @VoronoiPotato: I think you mean http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

Comment: @Soundz That has nothing to do with it. `instanceof` is not your regular comparison operator.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato - What's your point? It's clearly documented and expected behavior.

Comment: Clearly documented and quite counter-intuitive to anyone who is used to other languages, the chart comment helps to provide cultural context.

Comment: $foo = 5 + "10 Little Piggies"; // $foo is integer (15) 

If the op is aware of how php culture handles type casting it will help prevent them from being caught off guard again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [the documentation, example 5](http://php.net/instanceof): (emphasis mine)

> Although instanceof is usually used with a literal classname, it can
>   also be used with another object or **a string variable**:

```
$a = new MyClass;
var_dump($a instanceof $c); // $c is a string 'MyClass'
```

The result:

```
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

*Although instanceof is usually used with a literal classname, it can also be used with another object or a string variable*

http://php.net/instanceof

Answer (score 2):

The `instanceof` operator can work with classes, but also with a classname as string.

> Although instanceof is usually used with a literal classname, it can also be used with another object or a string variable

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

And there's the exact example you posted, so I don't know where yours is from, but...